# Inserting a row into Relational database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to c# and asp.net mvc. I'm building a HR portal for our company where a user can submit a leave form among other things... So I'm using mssql as the database server and using Entity Frame work to communicate with it. I have 3 entities, user (Containing user details), permissions (the user permissions for allowing actions in the app) and then the leave form table (where the leave form details are stored). There is a one to many relationship between user - permission and then a one to many relationship between user-leave. I am not fazed about the permissions as that gets created when the user account is being created.

The problem I am facing is, how do I add a leave form for a specific user? Below is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Leave(MasterViewModel model)
{
    DocSubViewModel mv = model.DSModel;
    int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]);
    try
    {
        using (HrDcpDBContainer db = new HrDcpDBContainer())
        {
            var leave = db.leaves.Create();
            leave.dateFrom = mv.DateFrom;
            leave.dateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
            leave.dateTo = mv.DateTo;
            leave.nrDays = mv.NrDays;
            leave.reason = mv.SpecialLeave;
            leave.TLApproval = null;
            leave.TLApprovalDate = null;
            leave.TLApprovalID = mv.TeamLeaderID;
            leave.DMApprovalDate = null;
            leave.DMApprovalID = mv.DepManagerID;
            leave.DMApproval = null;
            leave.type = mv.Type;
            leave.user = userId;
            db.leaves.Add(leave);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Leave Form submitted Successfully. You will be redirected shortly...";
        return View("result");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = ex;
        //ViewBag.Message = "Leave Form submitted Successfully. You will be redirected shortly...";
        return View("result");
    }
```

The problem comes in `leave.user = userId;`. It says:

> Cannot implicitly convert int to Portal.Model.user

I can't seem to find out how to do this...

Comment: it is because you're assigning `userId` to `user`. Is `user` an integer type? My guess is it's an object

Comment: leave.user  is the primary Key in the database

Comment: Is it leave.user.userid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it to put the `UserId` where your leave model is asking for a `User`.

Your relationship requires a User to go in there, so you'll have to update your code a little bit:

```
using (HrDcpDBContainer db = new HrDcpDBContainer())
{
    var leave = db.leaves.Create();
    leave.user = db.users.First(x => x.Id == userId);
}
```

This will put reference to the actual user in the new leave record. If you go later and check it out you'll see a column in the leave table called `user_Id` that has an integer value in it and is set as a foreign key to the users table.

Note that this will error if no user exists having the specified Id value. If you anticipate this to be a problem, rather use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.First()` and then account for the value being null before you add it to your new leave object.

Comment: Thanks, Makes so much sense but trying to figure this out on my own is difficult. C# is not a forgiving language. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: little typo there ... `x =.` should be `x =>`

Answer (score 0):

That's expected since `User` is a object and not `int`. What you should be doing probably is `leave.user.UserId = userId;` instead [Assuming `leave.user` is of type `User` which has a `UserId` property]

Comment: No assumption is necessary. OP confirmed the type of leave.user when he quoted the error message at the bottom of the question :)

Comment: @Ortund, yes but the actual assumption was that it does have a property named userid

Comment: Oh right, sorry I didn't see what you did in your answer there... Change blindness... I saw what I expected to see and I didn't expect to see you setting `leave.user.UserId` xD